# Unable to update button text and font icon on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change/update the text and font icon of a button on click event properly?

```js
$(".btn-warning").click(function() {
      $(this).toggle(function() {
          $('.btn-warning').text("Remove Filter <i class='fa fa-filter'></i>");
      }, function() {
          $('.btn-warning').text("Apply Filter <i class='fa fa-remove'></i>"); 
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Apply Filter <i class="fa fa-filter"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go.

```js
$(".btn-warning").click(function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    if ($btn.hasClass('x-on')) {
        $btn.removeClass('x-on').html("Apply Filter <i class='fa fa-filter'></i>");
    } else {
        $btn.addClass('x-on').html("Remove Filter <i class='fa fa-remove'></i>");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Apply Filter <i class="fa fa-filter"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`toggle` doesn't work how this code would like it to. It doesn't mean `do this` or `do something else` - When you `toggle` you cause JQuery to fade-out/in the element and the function call is performed when the animation completes.

So you `click` and fade out the element, but now there's nothing to `click` on to bring it back and your changes will not be seen.

To change the code on click we can simply set a variable on the function itself (`this.clicked`) and toggle the `html` of the element based on whether it's the first or second click. This will be determined by checking if `this.checked` is true or false.

```
$(".btn-warning").click(function() {
  if (this.clicked == undefined) this.clicked = false;
  this.clicked = !this.clicked;

  (this.clicked) ?
  $('.btn-warning').html("Remove Filter <i class='fa fa-filter'></i>") :
  $('.btn-warning').html("Apply Filter <i class='fa fa-remove'></i>");
});
```

```js
$(".btn-warning").click(function() {
  let btn = $(".btn-warning");
  if (this.clicked == undefined) this.clicked = false;
  this.clicked = !this.clicked;

  (this.clicked) ?
  btn.html("Remove Filter <i class='fa fa-filter'></i>") :
  btn.html("Apply Filter <i class='fa fa-remove'></i>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Apply Filter <i class="fa fa-filter"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** The JQuery [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method will toggle the button visibility, you don't need this one.

**(2)** If you need to change the **html** of an element, do not use the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method, instead use the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method. The `text()` method will not recognize the `html` markup as you want.

One approach you can use is detecting if the `<i>` tag inside the button has some class (Read about [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)), and then act based on this condition:

```js
$(".btn-warning").click(function()
{
    if ($(this).find("i").hasClass("fa-filter"))
        $(this).html("Remove Filter <i class='fa fa-remove'></i>");
    else
        $(this).html("Apply Filter <i class='fa fa-filter'></i>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
  Apply Filter <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think this will more-or-less get you started.

https://jsfiddle.net/3bq9fuwz/

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Apply Filter <i class="fa fa-filter"></i></button>

            $(".btn-warning").click(function() {
              $(this).html('It is a new name bro');
              $(this).find($(".fa")).removeClass('fa-filter').addClass('fa-remove');
            });
```